# React scripts start is giving Unexpected token error

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I have been using `create-react-app` to bootstrap react apps all this while.
But I am facing a really strange issue today.
After bootstrapping my app with `create-react-app`. I am facing the below issue after I run `npm start`

```
rbac-tutorial-app/node_modules/@hapi/joi/lib/types/object/index.js:254
                        !pattern.schema._validate(key, state, { ...options, abortEarly:true }).errors) {
                                                                ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (rbac-tutorial-app/node_modules/@hapi/joi/lib/types/func/index.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! rbac-tutorial-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the rbac-tutorial-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have already tried
- Deleting package.lock.json and deleting node modules and running `npm install` followed by `npm start` but the problem remains the same.
- Changing my node and npm versions.

NPM version I am using -> `6.9.0`
Node version I am using -> `v8.0.0`

Below is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "rbac-tutorial-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After couple of frustrating hours goggling for answers and trying different approaches, I figured it was not the problem with my code but rather problem while bootstrapping with `create-react-app` using `node version v8.0.0`.

So I deleted the entire project and followed below steps which solved my issue -

1. Deleted the entire project. Since I had not written much code so far, So I simply did that. If you have already written a lot of code ,please take a backup.
2. I installed `NVM(Node Version Manager)`.I used this link [How to install NVM in Ubuntu](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-nvm-node-version-manager-for-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) to install the same.
3. Once nvm is installed use `nvm install 12.0.0(or the node version > 8.0.0 which you would like to use)`. This was actually the issue for me. For `create-react-app` to bootstrap successfully you should use `node version > 8.0.0`.
4. After this I use `nvm use 12.0.0(or the node version which you have recently installed)`.
5. Check your node version using `node -v`. It should show the node version which you asked to use in step 4.
6. That's it. Now you should use `create-react-app` and bootstrap the app again.

This worked like a charm for me. Hope someone facing same issue will find it helpful.

Comment: Same issue. However, I use a node version > 8.0.0 (node 8.2.1, npm 5.3.0 exactly) and it doesn't work. This is server side, on the CI. On my PC, I use node 8.11.1 and npm 5.6.0, no issue...

Comment: In my case I had switched to version 6 of Node earlier in the day and forgot about it :D

Answer (score 1):

Just use below command to resolve the issue:

- 12.0.0 should be installed before it can be used

  - step 1: first `nvm install 12.0.0`
  - step 2: `nvm use 12.0.0`

**Note:** If node version 12.0.0 is already present, skip step 1

Answer (score 0):

When deploying to ***Heroku*** I got that same error and after looking for more solutions than the accepted one I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62278713/react-script-build-giving-error-while-deploying-to-heroku) apparently easier.

It seemed to be due to the spread operator, available from Node's version 8.6. It suggested to specify a greater that version and greaters in engines section of package.json (*"node" : ">=8.6"*).

After using that solution it complained: '*Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node*', pointing to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version.
This Heroku's support site suggests to use the same version you're locally running but it’s recommended to use an x in the patch to get the latest patch updates. At the end I ended up with *"node" : "12.x"*. This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I solved it by creating an .env file on the project root, and pasting this `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` inside the .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to .env file in the root of the project

```
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
PUBLIC_URL=/
```

Answer (score 0):

just run `npm install node`
it will install the latest version of the node to your file and fix the error.

Comment: How is this different from the other answers that suggest installing a newer version of node? Also the command you suggested installs node in the project, not globally, which is not something most people want and it does not necessarily install the newest version.