# react-script build giving error while deploying to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, npm

I am trying to deploy my create-react-app on heroku under my node/express server.
I am using the heroku postbuild script but I am getting an error about react-script build.
Well I am new to the backend side and not knowledged about heroku deployments.

```js
//my npde server scripts
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
//my client scripts
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  //The error log
  remote: /tmp/build_9c0331519287501c707a58e785c7cac2/client/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js:306
remote:         ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
remote:         ^^^
remote:
remote: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
remote:     at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
remote:     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
remote:     at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
remote:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
remote:     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
remote:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
remote:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
remote:     at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
remote:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
remote:     at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_9c0331519287501c707a58e785c7cac2/client/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:38:23)
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.eaz5f/_logs/2020-06-09T08_25_12_438Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! noode-server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the noode-server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.eaz5f/_logs/2020-06-09T08_25_12_454Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in this error line: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...`. It means Node can't recognise the ... syntax.

The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (...) is available from [Node.js v8.6 and up](https://node.green/#ES2018-features-object-rest-spread-properties-object-spread-properties). Make sure Heroku is using the right Node version by setting it in your `package.json` file:

```
{ 
  "engines" : { 
    "node" : ">=8.6" 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It got me in track of the good solution. I applied this but Heroku still complained: 'Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node', pointing to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version. This site suggests to use the same version you're locally running but it’s recommended to use an x in the patch to get the latest patch updates. At the end I ended up with "node" : "12.x"